# How to genearet dynamic UI on json response react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is that possible that after getting response from API in JSON format , we can draw dynamic UI , like if getting 5 attributes in JSON then 5 Textinput or if getting 10 then 10 textinput .
I need some help and direction . Please help .

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the [json-editor library](https://github.com/json-editor/json-editor), it allows generation of a web UI using [Json Schema](http://json-schema.org/).

Hope this helps.
Regards,
Omer.

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/json-editor/json-editor/issues/40) contains some information on how to use json-editor in React. I'm not 100% sure about react-native but you can try.
There's also [react-jsonschema-form](https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form) again for React but it's worth testing if it works for react-native.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54804549/on-picker-value-change-call-function-or-array-in-react-native?noredirect=1#comment96385594_54804549